# How can I add parameter to a stubbed response body in wiremock?

Tags: java, json, rest, server, wiremock

I'm using wiremock to stub the response of a dependent service. I need to use real data, because my system needs that data to properly do its job. I have a json that contains the stubbed response for an API call. It looks like this:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPattern": "/path"
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 200,
    "jsonBody": [
      {
        "secret": "secretInfoHere"
      }
    ],
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to know if it's possible to hide the ***secret*** value from that JSON and insert that information at runtime from an env var from example.

Ideally the secret would look like this:

```
"secret": ${SECRET_VALUE}
```

or

```
"secret": ""
```

I read this section, but it didn't turn up to be as helpful as I thought it would be: http://wiremock.org/docs/response-templating/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by following a similar approach to the one that can be found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wiremock-user/QZyrzhvReZE

I basically created a new class that extends `ResponseTransformer` and then I overridden the `transform` method.

Answer (score 0):

Response templating doesn't use the environment/system variables in its model so you won't be able to use it in this instance unfortunately.

Your best bet right now would be to write an implementation of `ResponseDefinitionTransformer` which reads the config value and performs the string replacement. I suspect this would only be a few lines of code.

Docs here: http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I went over those docs before posting my questions. It didn't help that much, though. I would have expected some actual examples from that documentation page.

What I'm saying is that, I would have liked to have a button or a link at the end of each code snippet that should redirect me to an working code sample on github.